# Python Global / Local Data From File Dialog Box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning python as a pastime and have run into some trouble accessing data ("lines") from a function.
I was hoping to create a label to display the number of lines after the function,but I am getting an error that says the variable is "not defined".
Why is this happening?

```
__author__ = 'alasdair'
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
import sys, Tkinter

from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
Mainwindow = Tk()
Mainwindow.title ("Test")
Mainwindow.geometry('600x400')
global lines

def openfile():
 name = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("TextDocument", "*.TXT;*.txt"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
 with open(name) as foo:
  lines = len(foo.readlines())

openfile = Button(Mainwindow,text = "Open File",width=20,command = openfile).place(x=25,y=45)
print(lines)
Mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines` variable is only defined in the function - `openfile()` , and is a local variable to it, you cannot access it outside the function (unless you declare it as global variable at the start of the function , though I would not recommend that).

Also , `openfile` is a callback function for the Button with `text = "Open File"` , and the function is not called untill the button is clicked.

But the `print(lines)` is executed immediately after the Button has been created, there is no guarantee that the button would be clicked before `print(lines)` is reached.

You should remove the `print(lines)` line , and print it inside the function -

```
def openfile():
 name = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("TextDocument", "*.TXT;*.txt"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
 with open(name) as foo:
  lines = len(foo.readlines()
  print(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,yes I can do that and it works.But I would l would like to if possible to use the data ("lines" ) in a tk label which I think I can only do after the button sync.

Comment: @AlasdairRyan You can create the label and all inside the function as well. Though all this would be good if you put the complete `Frame` (or App) as a single class, and do all this inside that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is return lines from your open file and then assign it to a variable like so:

```
def openfile():
     name = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("TextDocument", "*.TXT;*.txt"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
 with open(name) as foo:
     lines = len(foo.readlines())
    return lines

lines = openfile() # run before you tried to access the lines variable
```

Other things you may want to consider:

- Taking the filename as an argument to openfile()
- Not using the same variable name as a function name

Comment: That could work in terms of retrieving the valve,but as you know it calls the function.